# localization in asp.net-HTML controls

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my application i need different culture for HTML controls.
is it possible through the .resx file or is  there anyother methods.

```
 <ul>
   <li><a href="..">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Admin</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">View List</a></li>

 </ul>
```

How to apply localization for all the pages from master page?
or whether i need to apply the code for all the pages?
is there any method for applying the localization for javascript and Jquery other than creating separate script for different languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Localize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.localize%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) control.

Resharper shows a tip, when you select a piece of HTML to put it in a Resource.

In [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx) you can find a useful chapter about localization and globalization in ASP.NET.

You can set the current UI culture in the Session_Start of Global. How to change it is dependent on how localization of your web site is managed (if user can change it in a profile or whether it must be the one set in the browser etc).

Or you can set-up the web application to use the browser localization in [web.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0.aspx):

```
<globalization
    enableClientBasedCulture="true">
```